# Programmatically populate a Drupal form

Tags: forms, entities

I am very new to Drupal and trying to write a module. I have 2 entities - Membership and MembershipRequest and both are fieldable. A MembershipRequest is a request to the admin of the website to create or update (renew/delete) a Membership entity. On the MembeshipRequest form, I want to populate the form elements with Membership entity values that user are requesting to update. For example, on the request form's First name text box, I want to populate the Membership's First name. I have membership_id property in the the request entity. But the First name and other fields are attached to both entities via Field API.

I am not sure which object (and how) - $form, $form_state, $request - I need to modify so that the request form will show up with populated values.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Assuming your _MembershipRequest_ entity is already referencing a _Membership_ entity by ID, why not just display the referenced entity when the request is being viewed?

Comment: Yes, I am displaying it. But on the request form, I just want to populate values from membership entity so that user doesn't have to fill out the whole form.

Comment: Is the user able to request changes to specific fields? From the OP it sounds like the request is only to create or delete, not to modify.

Comment: No, the user can request to update also (any field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on programming this, and not use and configure contrib modules -

#### If fields were added to entity bundle via drupal admin UI

You can use `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`, and in the code there have the particular field populated with desired default value.

- hook_form_alter() would be invoked for all forms and you would have to have an if condition to target just the desired form id.
- hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() would be invoked for particular form.

#### If field was attached using Field API code (not the case for this question)

You would have an implementation of `hook_field_attach_form()` to attach fields to your MembeshipRequest entity. It would be in that hook implementation that you would set a `#default_value` to the desired form field.

#### Code to use in either of the cases above

```
$form['foo']['bar'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield', 
  '#title' => t('foobar'), 
  '#default_value' => _func_to_get_default_value($member_id), 
  '#description' => t('something something'),
  '#size' => 60, 
);  
// NOTE: Replace foo/bar with the particular field etc.
```

Comment: It does say 'programatically' in the title - my bad. This is a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, could you also tell how to set the default value of the field if the field is attached using field api? I made both entities fieldable and added firstname, lastname, email, etc. using the fields UI (thought that would be easy because then I wouldn't have to program the form code) :-(

Comment: I have updated the answer. A simple hook form alter should do in that case.

Comment: @SumeetPareek, thanks. I tried the above code and it works. The only problem is now I have to mention #type, #title, '#description' and all properties for all fields in the code again. If I only set #default_value, the field does not show up in the form. I used the admin UI to set up the fields so that the site admin can attach/remove fields without me touching the code. For now, I have put  $form[$key][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $arrayMember[$key]['und'][0]['value']; in the code. Not sure if it will work for all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Entity reference autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill).

> The Entity reference autofill module gives Entity reference fields an
>   option to populate other form fields with data from selected
>   referenced entities.

Comment: I am programming all of this so want to know I can modify ($form/$form_state/$request) to populate the form from the values of membership entity.